# Excel VBA to enter a formula in a cell based on the value of a cell with drop-down box

Tags: excel, vba

I have a drop down (via Data Validation) where a user can select BUs or RUs, and there are two tables below where the relevant data should be entered. Is there a VBA script that would enter a formula in the not selected table to convert other other tables data. For instance, if the user selected BUs from the drop down, then a formula of D159/10 should be calculated in cell K159.

[image]

I tried this code with no success:

```
Private Sub UOM_Formulas()

If Range("d155").Value = "BUs" Then
    Range("k159").Value = "=d159/10"
Else

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fill out *both* tables with formulas. When user enters values in a table, another table calculates.

Or adjust the next macro as you need:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = [D155].Address Then
    If Target = "BUs" Then
      [D159] = [D159].Value
      [K159] = "=D159/10"
    ElseIf Target = "RUs" Then
      [K159] = [K159].Value
      [D159] = "=K159/10"
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: That mostly works... When I click the dropdown in D155 and choose BUs, and then enter a value in D159, K159 remains blank until I click back into cell D155 

Comment: The formula appears in the destination cell as soon as D155 is reentered, and regardless the value was changed or not - it's expected behavior and it works for me. I am not able to reproduce behavior you described. Have no idea.

Comment: I modified the macro to avoid recursive references (it's not related to your comment).

Comment: I figured it out! I had SelectionChange, not Change selected. It works beautifully now. Thank you!

Comment: It's a kind of miracle! Did you not copy/paste the code? :-)